# Assigning a custom Event on a Custom object

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have created a custom JavaScript object that loads some images:

```
function myCustomObject(){
    //constructor and properties
    this.initializeImages(); //this function will initialize images and call every other function.
}


myCustomObject.prototype.initializeImages(){
    //some preperation code here
    imageObj = new Image();
    imageObj.onload = function (){
        //after doing some things here I will call all remaining functions
        if (allImagesLoaded=true){
            this.method1();
            this.method2();
            this.method3();
            //I want here to dispatch a custom event
            $.event.trigger({
                type: 'finish',
                customeEventProperty: value
            }
        }
    }

}
```

On my main code I want to create two different `customObjects`, and want each one of them to fire the event when they finish, but I want to know which one fired them.

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    var myCustomObject1, myCustomObject2;
    myCustomObject1  = new myCustomObject();
    myCustomObject2 = new myCustomObject();

    //if i do this I can't know which of the two fired the event
    $(document).on('finish', function);

    //How can I set up my event so I can do this?
    myCustomObject1.on('finish', function1);
    myCustomObject2.on('finish', function2);
  

});
```

In other words how can I know which one fired my custom event?

Comment: What kind of thing is `imageObj` inside `initializeImages()` ?

Comment: edited my initial post.It's an Image object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your customObjects are javascript-objects not jQuery-objects so you can't use `.on()`. You also can't trigger an event on them, because they are no DOM-Elements.But there are different ways to achieve what you want.

The first way sets an event-listener on  document and inside it's callback you can read which object has triggered. You also can set up a global counter variable to give your customObjects a unique number. The advantage is that you have only one central handler
for all finish-events.

```
var objCounter = 0;

function func1() {/* Do something when obj 1 has finished */}
function func2() {/* Do something when obj 2 has finished */}

function myCustomObject(){
    this.number = ++objCounter;
    this.initializeImages();
}

$(document).on('finish', function(event) {
    console.log(event.sender);
    console.log(event.imageObj);
    // now for example you can do:
    if (event.sender.number == 1) func1();
});

myCustomObject.prototype.initializeImages(){
    /* .... */
    var that = this, // this refers to the customObject
        imageObj = new Image();

    imageObj.onload = function (){
        /* ... */
        if (allImagesLoaded=true){
            /* ... */
            $.event.trigger({
                type: 'finish',
                sender: that,
                imageObj: imageObj,
                customeEventProperty: value
            });
        }
    };
}
```

A second simple way attaches the handler as properties to customObject:

```
function myCustomObject(callback){
    if (typeof callback == 'function') this.finish = callback;
    this.initializeImages();
}

myCustomObject.prototype.initializeImages(){
    /* .... */
    var that = this, // this refers to the customObject
        imageObj = new Image();

    imageObj.onload = function (){
        /* ... */
        if (allImagesLoaded=true){
            /* ... */
            if(that.finish) that.finish(); // execute finish if its there
        }
    };
}

// now you can create a customObject with integrated callback:
var myCustomObject1 = new myCustomObject( func1 );
```

Comment: objCounter is global variable right? I have myCustomObject on different js file, so I will have to put it there right?

Comment: @Apostolos You are right, it's kind of global. `objCounter` is best placed just before you define function `myCustomObject`. Have a look at the second solution too, it doesn't need events.

Comment: Which would you prefer? Or more likely what are the advantages each?

Comment: @Apostolos The firsts advantage: One function inside `$(document).on()` can handle all events coming from different objects. The seconds: It's simpler and keeps the 'finishing' private to each object. It's also possible to combine both solutions.